# stop/interrupt a thread after jdbc Driver has been deregister

Tags: java, multithreading, ojdbc

I want to close a thread by calling a method after the jdbc Driver has been deregister.

```
public class CleanupContextListener implements ServletContextListener{
    boolean driverDeregisterFlag = false;

        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
            Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
            while(drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
                Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
                ClassLoader driverClassLoader = driver.getClass().getClassLoader();
                ClassLoader thisClassLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
                if (driverClassLoader != null && thisClassLoader != null && driverClassLoader.equals(thisClassLoader)) {
                   try {
                       DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
                       driverDeregisterFlag = true;
                   } catch (SQLException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
                }
            }
            if (driverDeregisterFlag) {
                ConfigManager.stopCurrentThread();    
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm trying to call the ConfigManager.stopCurrentThread() and stop the current Thread.
ConfigManager is a class that implements Runnable.
stopCurrentThread(), is defined as an empty method in ConfigManager.
I want to put some code inside stopCurrentThread() and close the thread from ConfigManager.

How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve. Want to safelly stop some Runnable ?

Comment: I have tomcat errors. First I had the jdbc Driver error "The web application [***] registered the JDBC driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application..... has been forcibly unregistered". I got rid of this error but now I have running threads that are not closed after the jdbc driver is deregistered. 

In other words yes, I want to safely stop some Runnable after the driver is deregister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fragment of my code which is solving similar problem. Tested on c3p0 pool + tomcat 8, but you will be probably able to modify it to you needs.

```
/**
 * Destroying application context. We need to safely stop exporting thread
 * and do cleanup.
 * 
 * @param arg0
 *            reason for cleanup
 */
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(@NotNull ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    // Safely stop exporting service and shut down the application context
    super.contextDestroyed(arg0);

    // Close all JDBC connections
    C3P0Registry.getNumPooledDataSources();
    Iterator<?> it = C3P0Registry.getPooledDataSources().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        try {
            PooledDataSource dataSource = (PooledDataSource) it.next();
            dataSource.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error when closing connections ...", e);
        }
    }

    // This manually unregisters JDBC drivers, which prevents Tomcat 7 from
    // complaining about memory leaks with this class
    Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
        Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
        try {
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
            log.info(String.format("Unregistering jdbc driver: %s", driver));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error(
                    String.format("Error deregistering driver %s", driver),
                    e);
        }
    }

    // Waiting for daemon close() c3p0 jdbc pool thread
    Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
    for (Thread th : threadSet) {
        if (th.isDaemon()) {
            try {
                if (th.getName().equals(
                        "Resource Destroyer in BasicResourcePool.close()")) {
                    th.join();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.info("Shutdown waiting was interrupted ...");
            }
        }
    }
    // Clear all thread local variables, this prevents Tomcat 7 from
    // complaining about memory leaks
    immolate();

}

/**
 * Cleanup function which cleans all thread local variables. Using thread
 * local variables is not a good practice but unfortunately some libraries
 * are still using them. We need to clean them up to prevent memory leaks.
 * 
 * @return number of Thread local variables
 */
private int immolate() {
    int count = 0;
    try {
        final Field threadLocalsField = Thread.class
                .getDeclaredField("threadLocals");
        threadLocalsField.setAccessible(true);
        final Field inheritableThreadLocalsField = Thread.class
                .getDeclaredField("inheritableThreadLocals");
        inheritableThreadLocalsField.setAccessible(true);
        for (final Thread thread : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
            count += clear(threadLocalsField.get(thread));
            count += clear(inheritableThreadLocalsField.get(thread));
        }
        log.info("Immolated " + count + " values in ThreadLocals");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("ThreadLocalImmolater.immolate()", e);
    }
    return count;
}

/**
 * Cleaner for thread local map.
 * 
 * @param threadLocalMap
 *            thread local map to clean or null
 * @return number of cleaned objects
 * @throws Exception
 *             in case of error
 */
private int clear(@NotNull final Object threadLocalMap) throws Exception {
    if (threadLocalMap == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    final Field tableField = threadLocalMap.getClass().getDeclaredField(
            "table");
    tableField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object table = tableField.get(threadLocalMap);
    for (int i = 0, length = Array.getLength(table); i < length; ++i) {
        final Object entry = Array.get(table, i);
        if (entry != null) {
            final Object threadLocal = ((WeakReference<?>) entry).get();
            if (threadLocal != null) {
                log(i, threadLocal);
                Array.set(table, i, null);
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I cannot close the threads... still same error.. what you think I should try ? anyway, I don't want to close all the jdbc Connections. I want to use that simple function that I`ve posted and in addition close some other threads that haven't been closed.

Comment: Use join() to wait untill the JDBC thread is closed, but you need to know it's name.

Comment: can you be more precisely on this ? I`m pretty new working with threads.

Comment: see code under "Waiting for daemon" - I am getting all threads of my application, check if some of them are deamon threads (those threads will not close at the end of app if you will not close them manually), check by name, and use Thread.join() method - this method will cause your current thread to wait untill the joined thread dye. For more details about threads see http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077138/java-concurrency/introduction-to-java-threads.html and please note that  Java 8 has introduced many simplyfications to the thread model like streams and it's lambda functional programming.

Comment: I understand the point of what you wrote in your "Waiting for daemon".
I need to implement the immolate function too?

Comment: @Bogdan Coman Immolate function clears all thread local variables. Many third party libraries are using them, but do not clear them. So to awoid memmory leaks it is good practice to clean them.